# Как реализовать редактирование данных в таблице БД через веб-интерфейс asp.net core mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-mvc

Работаю над проектом asp.net, где необходимо реализовать работу клиента с базой данных. Необходимо добавить функции добавления, удаления и редактирования записей в таблицах. Задача простая, но наткнулся на такую вот структуру в базе данных:

[image: Связанные-таблицы-бд]

Как я уже выяснил, решение ввести вспомогательные таблицы Managers и CPEs было принято для избежания связей многие ко многим. Только вот вопрос: как реализовать редактирование таблицы Enterprises через пользовательский интерфейс. На asp.net работаю недавно, не сталкивался с такими случаями. Для редактирования других таблиц делал ссылку на вспомогательную страницу с формой, где получал данные от пользователя, выполнял необходимый запрос и перенаправлял на главную страницу. Вот пример того, как я делал это с остальными таблицами:
Есть таблица планируемых мероприятий, которая связана с таблицей предприятий, сотрудников, мероприятий и источников финансирования(см. рисунок)

[image: er-диаграмма]

Было создано отдельное представление для добавления записи:

```html
@model PlannedEvent

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Добавление планируемого мероприятия";
}

<h2>Добавление планируемого мероприятия</h2>

@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
    <h4>Планируемое мероприятие</h4>

    <p>
        Планируемое мероприятие <br>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.EventId, ViewBag.Events as SelectList)
    </p>

    <p>
        Предприятие <br>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.EnterpriseId, ViewBag.Enterprises as SelectList)
    </p>

    <p>
        Начало мероприятия <br>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateOfStart)
    </p>

    <p>
        Конец мероприятия <br>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateOfEnd)
    </p>

    <p>
        Объём <br>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Scope)
    </p>

    <p>
        Затраты <br>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Expenses)
    </p>

    <p>
        Экономический эффект <br>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EconomicEffect)
    </p>

    <p>
        Ответственный за проведение мероприятия <br>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.EmployeeId, ViewBag.Employees as SelectList)
    </p>
    <p>
        Номер финансирования <br>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.FinanceId, ViewBag.SourcesOfFinancing as SelectList)
    </p>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Запланировать мероприятие">
    </p>
}
```

Ну а для реализации в контроллере написан следующий код:

```cs
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Create()
{
    SelectList events = new(_context.Events, "Id", "Name");
    SelectList enterprises = new(_context.Enterprises, "Id", "Name");
    SelectList employees = new(_context.Employees, "Id", "Surname");
    SelectList financings = new(_context.SourcesOfFinancing, "Id", "Id");
    ViewBag.Events = events;
    ViewBag.Enterprises = enterprises;
    ViewBag.Employees = employees;
    ViewBag.SourcesOfFinancing = financings;
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(PlannedEvent plannedEvent)
{
    _context.PlannedEvents.Add(plannedEvent);
    _context.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

По итогу получается такой интерфейс:

[image: Интерфейс]

Как в такой же форме реализовать добавление, удаление и редактирование записей в таблице Enterprises? Ведь там уже целых 2 связи, а не 1, в случае, когда нам придётся выбирать менеджера и гл. энергетика предприятия.

Comment: [Getting Started with EF 6 using MVC 5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/) - предлагаю изучить этот туториал. В разделах Reading Related Data и Updating Related Data как раз решаются задачи похожие на ваши.

Comment: Меня смущает направление связей на диаграмме: у одного работника несколько менеджеров, а у одного менеджера - несколько предприятий. Не должно ли быть наоборот?

Comment: Один человек может быть менеджером, например, двух предприятий. В то время, как у предприятия может быть только 1 менеджер.

Answer (score 0):

Сначала создадим представление с формой для добавления записи

```
@model Enterprise

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Добавление предприятия";
}

<h2>Добавление предриятия</h2>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="OwnershipForm" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="OwnershipForm" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="OwnershipForm" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Adress" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Adress" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Adress" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <!-- Добавление выпадающего списка для выбора менеджера -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ManagerId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="ManagerId" class="form-control" asp-items="@ViewBag.Managers"></select>
                <span asp-validation-for="ManagerId" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <!-- Добавление выпадающего списка для выбора главного энергетика -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="CPEId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="CPEId" class="form-control" asp-items="@ViewBag.CPEs"></select>
                <span asp-validation-for="CPEId" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Теперь добавим методы в контроллер

```
public IActionResult Create()
{
    // Заполнение выпадающих списков данными из таблицы Employees
    ViewBag.Managers = new SelectList(_context.Employees, "Id", "Surname");
    ViewBag.CPEs = new SelectList(_context.Employees, "Id", "Surname");

    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Name,OwnershipForm,Adress,ManagerId,CPEId")] Enterprise enterprise)
{

    // Добавление записи в таблицу Enterprises
    _context.Add(enterprise);

    // Сохранение изменений в базе данных
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));

}
```

Аналогичным образом делается редактирование записей. В представление необходимо добавить скрытое поле для идентификатора.